# Fill dropdown and radio button choice to proceed to right url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, woocommerce

I am trying to force my customers to do two choices on cart.php before they can proceed to the checkout. based on those choices the customer will be redirected to the correct page.
But its not showing as i want in woocommerce cart page.

html

```
   To  proceed please fill this following steps.<br>
   Country:<br><select id="selectMe">
   <option value="none">Choose country</option>
   <option value="sweden">sweden</option>
   <option value="other">other</option>
   </select>
   <br><br><br>

   <div id="sweden" class="group">
   <BLOCKQUOTE><font size="4" face="Alice">Choose payment method</font><HR>
   <pre>
   <form name="jump"> 
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://facebook.com">Klarna checkout<br>
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://google.com">Paypal<br>
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://paypal.com">cash on delivery<br>

   <input type="button" value="Proceed to checkout" onClick="linkselect(this.form)">
   </form>
   </div>
   <div id="other" class="group">
   <BLOCKQUOTE><font size="4" face="Alice">Choose payment method</font><HR>
   <pre>
   <form name="jump"> 
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://paypal.com">Paypal<br>

   <input type="button" value="Proceed to checkout" onClick="linkselect(this.form)">
   </form>
   </div>
```

javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#none').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
       })
    });

    function linkselect(what) {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    if (what.a[i].checked == true)
    location.href = what.a[i].value;
       }
    }
```

Comment: what is "a" in the function?

Comment: name of radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that you need to look at:

1. Do not have multiple forms unless there is no other way around
2. Wrap all html attributes in quotes.
3. Do not have pre tags. Style your elements to suit your UI

Take a look at the below HTML/JS

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/hq8cB/)

Include the below jQuery in the "head" section of your page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML (restructured)

```
<select id="selectMe">
  <option value="none">Choose country</option>
  <option value="sweden">sweden</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
</select>


<div id="wrapper" class="group" style="display:none;">
  <BLOCKQUOTE><font size="4" face="Alice">Choose payment method</font></BLOCKQUOTE><HR>
  <form name="jump">

    <div class="sweden" style="display:none;">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="http://facebook.com" />Klarna checkout<br>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="http://google.com" />Paypal<br>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="http://paypal.com" />cash on delivery<br>
    </div>

    <div class="other" style="display:none;">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="http://paypal.com"/>Paypal<br>
    </div>

    <input id="checkout" type="button" value="Proceed to checkout" />

  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var group = $('.group');
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('form[name="jump"] :radio').prop('checked', false);
        var selected = $(this).val();
        group[selected !== 'none'? "show" : "hide"]();
        group.find('div').hide();
        $('.'+selected).show();
    });

    $('#checkout').bind('click', function() {
        var selectedVal = $('form[name="jump"] :radio:checked').val();
        if ( selectedVal ) {
            //alert (selectedVal);
            window.location.href = selectedVal;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work! Only thing is that its not loading in browser? maybee im not writing it right in the php?

Comment: Did you comment the alert and uncomment the location.href line like in my edits?

Comment: not loading in browser? can you move the jquery code to the bottom of your page? may be just before the </body> tag? and what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I dont know actually. im not very god at this. im trying to add i to cart.php in woocommerce. when i go to chrome i get this: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: I think jQuery is missing on your page. See my edits.

Comment: I added the jquery in header.php inside <head> and now i get page blank if i select an option.

Comment: Sorry mate, I have actually helped you with your specific issue. You seem to have other problems on your web page that you need to debug and fix as I can't keep assuming something that may not be the thing at all. Good luck.

Comment: No problem. thnak you very much for the help. i´ll try to fix it!

Comment: If at all this answer was helpful, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

there have been more issues with your code and i had to change a couple of things.
here is a working fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/W2534/1/ 
*(note that the jsfiddle won't forward you to the urls, cause it refuses to display external links, but you can see that it works using your browser's console - "F12" button turns developer mode with console on in most browsers)*

in your html-code i added an id to your form and to your button (for jquery identification):

```
   To  proceed please fill this following steps.<br>
   Country:<br><select id="selectMe">
   <option value="none">Choose country</option>
   <option value="sweden">sweden</option>
   <option value="other">other</option>
   </select>
   <br><br><br>

   <div id="sweden" class="group">
   <BLOCKQUOTE><font size="4" face="Alice">Choose payment method</font><HR>
   <pre>
   <form name="jump" id="myForm"> 
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://facebook.com">Klarna checkout<br>
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://google.com">Paypal<br>
   <input type=radio name=a value="http://paypal.com">cash on delivery<br>

   <input type="button" value="Proceed to checkout" id="mybutton">
   </form>
```

in your javascript i removed your linkselect-function, because you don't need it.
i use the click-event on the button with the id "mybutton", and can identify the checked radiobox by jquery-selectors as seen here:

```
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(e){
    document.location.href=$('input[name=a]:checked', '#myForm').val();
});
```

Comment: Did not work. When i acces the cart.php on my broser it shows the radio button fields. I want them to be hidden before they choose country. and if the choose sweden the should get all options and if they choose any other they will only get to choose paypal. then the button bring them to right url

Comment: so i guess the main problem was, that you did not include jquery?
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`